# Ember JS component accessing store

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know if it considered good practice in Ember.js to inject the ember data store in a component to be able create/delete records directly from the component instead of bubbling up to the route controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what core team are discussing about this topic.

https://youtu.be/y7aHMj6VVJY?t=1127

My take is: it depends. Usually, I will do dumb components mostly which will not access store for doing CRUD operations. In some cases, If the components data do not depend on the URL or not critical data to UI then I will make my component as smart component which can do all CRUD operation.

Answer (score 0):

Ember follows a data-down, actions up convention. Until routable components are released, you can inject the store to components to fetch data however you should persist data at the controller level.

This will ensure that the UI a level above the component remains synced